# from hapi to a http-server image

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

my knowledge in backend is not the best...

I am having issues wrapping my head around this.

I have an ng2 upload image, from there it will do a post req to the api, however I would like to have a server (http-server from node) just to add the files there, but I have no idea how to go from here :(

so ng2 (FE) -> Hapi (API) -> http-server (files storage)

These are my files
**upload.provider.js**
    const fs = require('fs');

```
class UploadProvider {
  constructor(path, request, reply) {
    this.path = path;
    this.data = request.payload;
    this.reply = reply;
    this.image();
  }

  image() {
    if (this.data.uploadFile.hapi.filename) {
      const name = this.data.uploadFile.hapi.filename.replace(/\ /g,'-');
      const path = this.path + name;
      const file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

      file.on('error', (err) => { 
        console.error(err) 
      });

      this.data.uploadFile.pipe(file);

      this.data.uploadFile.on('end', (err) => { 
        var ret = {
          filename: this.data.uploadFile.hapi.filename.replace(/\ /g,'-'),
          headers: this.data.uploadFile.hapi.headers
        }
        this.reply(JSON.stringify(ret));
      })
    }
  }
}

module.exports = UploadProvider;
```

**teaser.controller.js**

```
const upload = require('../providers/upload.provider');
const Teaser = require('../model/teaser.model');

var teaser = {
  upload: (request, reply) => {
  new upload('http://127.0.0.1:8080/teaser-images/', request, reply);
},

....
```

I keep getting this output:

> { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'http://192.168.33.1:8080/teaser-images/IX4A6789.jpg'
>     errno: -2,
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'open',
>     path: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/teaser-images/IX4A6789.jpg' }

Would really appreciate any help, this has been bugging me.

And I would really like to understand better the concept around stream buffers.

Best,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot one of the most important facts of browsers... they are based on GET.

I was trying to send the images to a place where it was not a server. after creating an http-server on a folder:

```
new upload('../images', request, reply);
```

then adding an `http-server` on that folder I was able to access the images I wanted.